# Problem on installing ZKTECO linux SDK: cannot run build.sh

Tags: c++, linux, .so, zkteco

I tried to install ZKTECO Linux SDK on my ubuntu 20.04

It shows an error when running build.sh

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: ../lib/x86/linux-64/libzksensorcore.so, needed by ./lib64/libzkfv.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libidkit.so.2: undefined reference to `MD5@OPENSSL_0.9.8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I exported the .so files to the classpath and ld_library but nothing changed

I am open to any suggestion

Comment: Please share the download link, let us try and update you..